# Insert row based on existing row and update the existing row after (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table "tablea" with column "a" and "b"

In the table is a row with `a = 1` and `b = 3`

Now I want to produce a Postgres SQL query which inserts a new row with `a=x` and `b = 3`, where `x` is some provided value and `3` is gotten from the existing row.

In the same go, I want to update the existing row to `a = 1` and `b = x`.

In pseudo code, this would be something similar to

```
first = select(a=1) limit 1
second = (x, first.b)
first = (first.a, x)
```

I cannot imagine how to do this in SQL. Currently, I do a select in my application and build the insert and update and send those to the db together.

This means 2 roundtrips to the db, and have ~60.000 of these queries I need to send. Takes quite a while.

If I could implement this in a single query, I could just build the 60.000 queries and send them to the db all at once = much faster

Comment: The `a` is an auto-increment primary key then?  Or just a primary key?

Comment: Nope. Pk is not relevant to this example. In fact, in my specific care, the table has no keys at all

Comment: Then how do you know which record is the "first" one you get the `b` value from?  How do you select it?

Comment: Found by looking for rows with a = 1

Comment: So multiple rows have a=1.  How do you distinguish between them to only set the b of one of them?

Comment: They dont. Consider a and b unique in this example